# Magento Cloud upgrade issue

Tags: magento2-cloud

I want to upgrade the Magento cloud version from 2.2.4 to 2.3.1. We cloned a branch to the local environment and then upgraded the site. Running the site in the local and it's confirmed that the version is upgraded to 2.3.1. We moved the required files from GitHub to the cloud rebuild branch. The version of the file is 2.3.1 but we are getting an error that DB is not upgraded.

> "{"0":"Please upgrade your database: Run \"bin/magento
>   setup:upgrade\" from the Magento root directory.\n"

As we cannot run setup upgrade, not sure how to resolve this issue.
Can anyone help us with this?

Comment: can you run:  "composer update" command?

Answer (score 0):

You can run php bin/magento setup:upgrade command by connecting SSH

Comment: you can push again with sample commit , like you can add some comments on any file, and push changes to cloud.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would be to update the version of the metapackage in your `composer.json`, run a composer update locally and then git push the updated lock and json.

1. `composer update "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":">=2.3.1 < 2.3.2"`
2. `git add composer.lock composer.json`
3. `git commit -m "Upgrading to Magento 2.3.1"`
4. `git push`

ECE-Tools runs `setup:upgrade` during the deploy phase which will upgrade your database appropriately.